# Java SimpleDateFormat format for 02-Sep-10. 16:55PM

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Using simpleDateformat I have to format a Date object as following

> 02-Sep-10. 16:55PM

Comment: I am not responsible for your specific requirements, but I'd like to just point out that you are going to introduce i18n defect. If for instance this date and time should be presented to user, I would use DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT, DateFormat.DEFAULT, aLocale), where aLocale is an instance of java.util.Locale for current user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  String DATE_FORMAT = "dd-EEE-yy. h:mm a"
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
```

by the way, 16:55 PM -- PM is not required... 4:55 PM would make sense :)

Answer (score 4):

```
dd-MMM-yy. HH:mma
```

but 16pm doesn't make sense - it is obviously PM. Either use `hh:mma`, or use `HH:mm`